# Reversing a List from a Context-Free Grammar

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

Let's say I have a struct_declaration_list of the following type. How do I reverse it?

```
struct_declaration_list
    : struct_declaration
    | struct_declaration_list struct_declaration
    ;
```

P.S. Sorry I don't know the exact name of this kind of list so I can't search. I just have this grammar.

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse"? Could you give some examples?

Comment: @svick Probably too late. I've got a similar confusion as OP. My interpretation of "reverse" is that: given a grammar rule (such as the one in the Q) that defines the order of evaluation in the *form of self-recursion*, how to obtain a *sequential list* where elements are in the order of the defined order of evaluation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very precise. I assume you want the list of `struct_declaration` to start from the other end in the parse tree.

Your grammar gives you a `struct_declaration_list` that looks like

```
         SDL
        /   \
      SDL    SD
     /   \
   SDL   SD
  /   \
SDL   SD
 |
SD
```

If you reverse the order in the second part of the rule, you reverse "the pointers" in the list, which may be understood as reversing the order.

```
struct_declaration_list
    : struct_declaration
    | struct_declaration struct_declaration_list
    ;
```

Then the parse tree  looks like:

```
   SDL
  /   \
 SD   SDL
     /   \
    SD   SDL
        /   \
       SD   SDL
             |
            SD
```

The left-to-right order of SD is in both cases that of their occurrence in the input string (the program).

Comment: This would flip the order of evaluation if the rule is intended as a self-recursion definition. I've added a comment under OP explaining my interpretation of the problem OP's facing.